# Variadic template aliases or functions?

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates

Supposing one needs to obtain a logical value based on a 
pack of template parameters, is there a reason to prefer an alias approach
vs a function approach?

Example:

```
template<bool...> struct bool_pack;
template<bool... bs> 
using all_true = std::is_same<bool_pack<bs..., true>,
                              bool_pack<true, bs...>>;
```

as opposed to

```
template<class none=void>
constexpr bool all_true() { return true; }

template<bool First, bool... Rest>
constexpr bool all_true() {
  return First and all_true<Rest...>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Time required for compiling your example implementations

... should be **measured**, of course. That said, I have seen micro-benchmarks where the `std::is_same` approach leads to significantly shorter compile times; even compared to the C++17 [fold expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) `(true && ... && bs)` with the respective compilers. The recursive "function approach" you gave as an example should be clearly inferior in compile-time performance.

Note, however, that one could surely offer the most convenient interface by providing a wrapper around the most "efficient" (regarding compile-time effort) implementation.

## Convenience in using the "interface"

Given these two choices, **I would prefer the alias approach**. If you need the result of that helper as a type (for inheritance, template-metaprogramming with specializations, or for tag dispatch), the alias yields cleaner syntax compared to, say, `std::bool_constant<all_true_v<some_condition(), some_other_condition()>()>`. In the other direction, it is simple to obtain a value of type `bool` from the alias: `all_true<some_condition(), some_other_condition()>{}` (relying on [implicit type conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant#std::integral_constant::operator_value_type)).

Since C++14, yet another (fancy?) choice is to provide a value by a constexpr variable template which has either type `std::true_type` or `std::false_type`. By implicit conversion to `bool` it can readily be used where plain `true` or `false` is required, but it can also be passed as a function argument without losing its compile-time guarantee.

```
template<bool... bs>
constexpr auto all_true_c = typename std::is_same<
    bool_pack<true, bs...>, bool_pack<bs..., true>
>::type{};
```

It may be a good strategy to follow the naming conventions used in the `<type_traits>` header of modern C++ **providing both forms**. If some utility is supposed to provide a value, one finds *helper variable templates* such as [`std::is_same_v`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same#Helper_variable_template):

```
template<class T, class U>
inline constexpr bool is_same_v = is_same<T, U>::value;// (since C++17)
```

if some helper is supposed to provide a type, one finds *helper types* such as [`std::decay_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay#Helper_types):

```
template<class T>
using decay_t = typename decay<T>::type;// (since C++14)
```

... in addition to the conventional utilities without suffix, respectively.